# Calculating the probability of adjacent squares, not both white, on a 6x6 board

Tags: probability

**Problem**
On a $6 \times 6$ board, the six squares along one diagonal are shaded gray and all other tiles are white. Two tiles are said to be adjacent if they share a side. What is the probability that two adjacent tiles, chosen at random, are not both white?  (I have a `tikzpicture` included in this problem. I would appreciate assistance in replacing the following code with a pdf image.)

[image]

In the future you can just compile it yourself on websites for example [here](http://quicklatex.com/). But it is encouraged on the site that you use MathJax and not images wherever  it is possible to do.

**Answer**
I got a probability of $20/50 = 2/5$. Is that correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compute the probability of?

Comment: Compile the `LaTeX` code. Include `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble.

Comment: This site uses [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) which is technically different than $\LaTeX$.  There is a great deal of overlap between the two in terms of syntax for usual math equations, however a lot of the page formatting and special-use packages aren't available for use here.  Instead of including code and expecting *us* to render the image and replace it for you, how about you render it yourself.  You can then screenshot the image using commonly included tools in most operating systems such as snippingtool in windows and include the image yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, just describe the problem *with words* and don't rely on an image.  All of the code as it appears now obscures the content of the question.

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: you can use sites such as http://quicklatex.com/ to generate pictures like : http://quicklatex.com/cache3/e3/ql_abf208e692d4c09e87e52872cd9001e3_l3.png but on the site it is encouraged to use MathJax compatible code.

Comment: As for an approach to the problem, presumably each pair of adjacent squares are equally likely to have been selected.  Instead of looking at the squares themselves, look at the *edges*.  Each interior edge corresponds with a selection of two adjacent squares and vice versa.  How many interior edges are there?  How many of those interior edges are adjacent to a non-white square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you tried to include the code, since the description is all perfectly understandable:

> The following figure depicts 36 tiles arranged in 6 rows and 6 columns; all six tiles along one diagonal are shaded gray, and the remaining tiles are white. Two tiles are said to be adjacent if they share a side. What is the probability that two adjacent tiles, chosen at random, are not both white?}

Well, you have $5$ pairs of adjacent tiles in each row and in each column, giving $12 \cdot 5 = 60$ pairs of adjacent tiles. Of those, 1 pair in the 'outside rows and columns is a pair that involves a gray square, and for the other rows and columns 2 pairs involve a gray square, so that is $4\cdot 1 + 8 \cdot 2=20$ pairs that involve a gray square.

Hence, the probability that two adjacent tiles, chosen at random, are not both white is $\frac{20}{60} = \frac{1}{3}$

So I guess you just miscounted the number of all possible adjacent pairs!

Comment: Yes, like an idiot, I said that there were $5^{2}$ adjacent pairs in each row and in each column ... which total 50 pairs.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire :) easy mistake! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer ( just way too long for a comment), you could just use something like:

$$\begin{smallmatrix}\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\\\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\\\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\\\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\\\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\\\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:yellow}{\begin{matrix}& &\\& &\end{matrix}}\!\!\!\style{background-color:red}{\begin{matrix} & &\\& &\end{matrix}}\end{smallmatrix}$$
to make it but with more care than I did maybe.

Comment: The OP has two colors, grey and white, but grey squares lie only on one diagonal; the other 30 squares are all white.

Comment: okay so wrap the red coloring around the smallmatrix and then only color in the diagonal matrices making up the squares ? still can't get the line spacing to work. back to editing it to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: or do it less stupidly with arrays and style.